# automatically include class library

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I wrote a class library and I know how I can use it, but before I can use the library in any Project, I have to add a reference to the library.

Now I want to know whether it's possible to tell Visual Studio to automatically add the reference to my library.

I'm using: Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sort of.  I don't think there is any plugin (nor should their be) that as soon as you open a project, any project, it will just add additional libraries.

That being said, you can always create your own project templates, so when you start a new website or a new app, it will automatically include what ever stuff you wanted by default.  Including your library choices.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own project template and then when you create new project, you would pick your template

[VS Project Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer: No. You have to specify the reference to your library wherever you're using it. It would of course be possible to write a tool that finds references automatically, but that's a complicated thing. And there are Visual Studio extensions (such as Resharper) that will suggest adding the reference for you. But in the end, the reference has to be there one way or another.